# Calling a hash parameter via .where() in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a model where one of it's values is represented further by a hash of data.

Calling `Market.first.extra_data['zip']` works well in the console to grab the first row's zip value.

However, when I try to do the opposite and search by a particular zip within the .extra_data hash using 
`Market.where(:extra_data['zip'] => 23462)`...I get an error that says

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

What is the proper way to search this nested hash using the .where() method?

(Rails beginner)

EDIT 1:
after entering `Market.where("extra_data -> 'zip' = '23462'")` I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json -> unknown
LINE 1: ...ECT "markets".* FROM "markets"  WHERE (extra_data -> 'zip' =...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add     explicit type casts.
: SELECT "markets".* FROM "markets"  WHERE (extra_data -> 'zip' = '23462')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist:    json -> unknown
LINE 1: ...ECT "markets".* FROM "markets"  WHERE (extra_data -> 'zip' =...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "markets".* FROM "markets"  WHERE (extra_data -> 'zip' = '23462')
```

Edit 2:
calling `Market.where("extra_data @> (:key => :value)", :key => 'zip', :value => '23462')` causes an error that looks like:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown => unknown
LINE 1: ...ts".* FROM "markets"  WHERE (extra_data @> ('zip' => '23462'...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "markets".* FROM "markets"  WHERE (extra_data @> ('zip' => '23462'))
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown => unknown
LINE 1: ...ts".* FROM "markets"  WHERE (extra_data @> ('zip' => '23462'...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "markets".* FROM "markets"  WHERE (extra_data @> ('zip' => '23462'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two query notations. Write something like

```
Market.where("extra_data -> 'zip' = '23462'")
```

or alternatively

```
Market.where("extra_data @> (:key => :value)", :key => 'zip', :value => '23462')
```

(assuming you are referring to using postgresql hstore fields)

More information and examples can be found in the docs of [activerecord-postgres-hstore gem](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore) (the original gem, which is now part of rails 4) or e.g. [here](http://www.schneems.com/post/19298469372/you-got-nosql-in-my-postgres-using-hstore-in-rails/)

Comment: Ok, I found another way to write a query. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to be sure: it _is_ a hstore column?